# Upgraded app to MVC 4, AUTH_USER is blank

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic, iis-6

I have a hybrid classic ASP + ASP.NET MVC 4 application running under Win Server 2k3 (IIS6) which we have upgraded to use MVC 4.

The ASP app is attached to the .NET application via a virtual directory. They run in the same application pool (if that matters). This particular app is an admin control panel, and uses basic authentication:

[image]

Before upgrading the project, when access the url for the virtual folder, the browser would display a login prompt, where I enter my domain-qualified username and password. The ASP code then retrieves the user name via `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_HEADER")`, compares that against an application-level permissions list stored in the database, and enables or disables features in the admin site based on that.

After upgrading the project, I still get the login prompt, but `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` returns an empty string.

I've added the old project into a new website so I can run them in parallel on the same server. The old code continues to work. The new code refuses to. The `admin` virtual directory in each version of the .NET application points to the same physical location on disk, and the authentication configuration for the folder in both .NET apps is identical.

Suggestions? Note that the MVC 4 app is using the .NET 4 framework, not .NET 4.5, which is not installed on the server.

**Note** that, although the `default domain` field in the screenshot is blank, it is properly configured. I've removed it from the image for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER") can be obtained when you configured your application to use Forms authentication not Windows Authentication. If it is Windows Authentication you should use Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")

Comment: Interesting... I'm fighting a situation where I have a hybrid classic ASP/ASP.NET app using Windows auth, where on the ASP pages, AUTH_USER pulls the user just fine. But on the ASP.NET pages (running on .NET v4.0), AUTH_USER produces the app pool's account but LOGON_USER produces the correct account. Furthermore, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name also produces the app pool account. I wonder why this is the case...

Comment: An update for anyone who runs into a similar issue - it looks like this happened in my case because I had the authenticatedUserOverride setting set to useWorkerProcessUser. This was done so we could use Windows auth but have IIS use the app pool account to access files on-disk. But a side effect of this is that AUTH_USER, REMOTE_USER and most of the other standard methods for obtaining the client's username will return the app pool account instead. The workaround is to use the LOGON_USER server variable, which seems to be the only one that still holds the client's username in this scenario.